# Where can I find registered company data through web services

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, companies, india

I am looking to find accurate company search information for companies registered within India and USA (same as [companies House](https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/) API service provided for UK ).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If it's not on [opencorporates](https://opencorporates.com/), I doubt you'll find it anywhere else.

Have a chat to the people there if you're still looking.

Answer (score 0):

Try data.gov.in for open data on India, for the US, you will need to go to each "Secretary of State" (SOS) website, and inquire about business license data. Some states (Florida, Alaska, Texas, etc.) offer it for free, most states, you have to pay for it.